# validating json schema with nested objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a JSON schema that will validate that 'ewb_query' is an object, but I would like to specify that the values in the object are only strings (but any keys are valid, not just name and age like in the example below).

I.e. I want values such as

```
"ewb_query":{"name":"jeff","age":32},
```

but not

```
"ewb_query":{"another_level":{...}},
```

This verifies that ewb_query is an object, but doesn't check that it's not nested.

```
'ewb_query' =>{
    type => 'object',
},
```

I tried this, but that seems to be invalid syntax:

```
'ewb_query' =>{
    type => 'object',
    properties => {
        type => 'string'
    },
},
```

Ideas? (pardon the perl syntax; that's what I'm using to generate my JSON schema)

Answer (score 0):

This achieves what you need:

{
"type":"object",
"additionalProperties":{"type":"string"}
}